# Storing data for machine learning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, storage

I am currently in the process of developing a machine learning application, where my users can upload their own data to train models. Furthermore, the users must be able to extend their uploaded data with new data (append new data to it). I am in a bit of doubt when it comes to actually store this (and whether or not it should be in a DB)

The data source can be:

- CSV file
- Excel file

As each file is unique, the column names will also be dynamic. For example, see below:

```php
// File_1.csv
comment
----------
Some text here
another text here
```

```php
// File_1.xlsx
ingredient
----------
tomato
strawberry
```

At some point, after the data has been uploaded, the user should be able to extend it (append new data to it). For example:

```php
// File_1 data:
text added at a later date
```

## Labels

Now, after the data has been uploaded for each model, a user must be able to add labels to it (for example for text classification). For simplicity, let's assume that we have two labels: `label_one` and `label_two`.

In order to store this, I was thinking of creating a table called `model_data`.

[image]

Inside this table, I would, for each model, save the data in the `data` column (in JSON). Something like:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "text":"Some text here",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":true,
               "label_two":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"Another text here",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":true,
               "label_two":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"tomato",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"strawberry",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"text added at a later date",
         "labels":[
            {
               "label_one":false,
               "label_two":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is this even a feasible way to store such data? Typically, data for ML tasks often consists of large datasets with thousands of rows.

## Alternative

I have also considered just using a filesystem to maintain this, and then store data for each model in a CSV file. So whenever a user uploads some data (and extends it), it will be added to a new CSV file.

Comment: in a rdms we like to have our data in relationships and normalized, stporing fixed data in json comma or some other means of delimiter, is possisble and there are in newer ve4rsion quite a few new functions to handle that data, it os still sometimes a pain  thta said see if https://github.com/mldbai/mldb and other documnet based is not a better choice

Comment: To discuss "how to store the data" we need to hear "how the data will be fetched".  That is, please sketch out how you will use the data -- always all the data?  various slices of the data?  Etc.

Comment: I agree with @RickJames. The question "how the data will be inserted, selected, updated, deleted" is necessary to determine data storage. Another question, if your database is distributed, is "how your database should be synchronized between hosts".

Comment: Users will select the columns they want to store when uploading the csv/excel file. I will need to have the option to update specific lines in the CSV file (for example, a user can overwrite the content of a specific line in a specific file). Furthermore, users should also be able to delete specific lines.